# Xubuntu running games EXTREMELY slow

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, wine, games, steam

So I've lately been trying to get my games back that I used to play on Windows because I had just switched to Xubuntu. But when running any game I see that the games are running EXTREMELY slow. I don't have integrated graphics. I have 8GB ddr3 RAM and 2GB nvidea graphics card. My specific computer model is the ASUS G750JW ROG gaming laptop. It doesn't just happen when I'm using WINE but also when I'm just using the regular steam client. Games will usually run at around 2-10fps. I don't have any bad blocks on my hard disk(I did the badblocks command). But I'm still unsure because games start to run slower when I turn up the resolution. Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary Nvidia driver from the Ubuntu Drivers dialogue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the original xorg driver for the card. use `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` to install some of the nvidia proprietary drivers and enable them with the special software dialog in the software sources window in the software center.

Comment: Yes I'm using the proprietary driver nvidia gave me to use but the games are still running very slow.

Comment: which one? and what games are you talking about?

Comment: I'm currently using the 331.38 proprietary driver from nvidia. I have also tried the one they recommended which was the 340.24 driver but I got the same results. I have tried running the following games. Steam: democracy 3, only if, civ 5. Under battle.net in WINE: Hearthstone. When I try to start steam without WINE it says: "OpenGl GLX extension not supported by display", if that helps any.

Comment: @user305920 perhaps this http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/1/648814395823405268/ or this http://icecrash.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/ubuntu-12-04-opengl-glx-extension-not-supported-by-display/ will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't much you can do because Xubuntu and Linux in general are not suitable for playing decent games. The reason is that graphics card manufacturers don't make adequate drivers for Linux (because it is not profitable). You better leave your system dual-boot. Play games in Windows and do other things in Xubuntu. Although 2D games should work well in Xubuntu.